# Why scanner input shows error in this specific case?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner, user-input

The program asks user to input some amounts and that amount(s) will be stored into an array.
But in my case, while inputting amount, the program shows the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at bankapplication.DepositWithdraw.deposit(DepositWithdraw.java:17)
    at bankapplication.BankApplication.main(BankApplication.java:46)
```

**My code**

```
package bankapplication;

import java.util.*;

public class DepositWithdraw {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int TransacNum;
    double withAm;
    int depAmArr[] = new int[TransacNum];

    public void deposit() {
        System.out.println("Depositing:\nHow many transaction you want to make? ");
        TransacNum = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < TransacNum; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter amount " + (i + 1) + ":");
            depAmArr[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("You are done! Choose other option if you want to continue.\n");
    }

}
```

***[NOTE: this class and it's method are meant to be called in my main class. I haven't shown my main class here, but I will edit the post if needs]***

Comment: `int depAmArr[] = new int[TransacNum];` when this statement is executed, `TransacNum` has still the default value (0 for an `int`). Move the array instantiation after the first `input.nextInt();`. Java is like Excel.

Comment: you are declaring an array of size 0 that is why the outofboundsexception.
create array after reading TransacNum in deposit() not before.

Comment: ZouZou, thatnks, it answers my question. anyway, why not writing an answer rather than commenting? I could accept ur answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TransacNum`, by default is `0`, until you assign it a value. The problem is that you use it to initialize `depAmArr` **before that**. Just initialize it after `TransacNum`, and you should be fine:

```
TransacNum = input.nextInt();
depAmArr[] = new int[TransacNum];
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you never initilize it with the size you got from the user input.
The class initilization has put default on all class members, `TransacNum` included. (value: 0)
Those the size of the array was set to array with the size of 0.

You should only create the array when the size is known. **i.e** After the user enters the size.

Example:

```
TransacNum = input.nextInt();
depAmArr[] = new int[TransacNum]
```

Also, You should change `int depAmArr[] = new int[TransacNum];` into `int depAmArr[];`

Answer (score 1):

You defind the defAmArr before transSum got any vaule.
That caused the array to be with a different value (or without value).
to solve it just do the
new int[transSum];
after you are getting he value to transSum